# max_input_vars limited in PHP 5.2.17

Tags: .htaccess

My hosting provider is using PHP 5.2.17 and I have problems with max_input_vars that is set to 1000

I am using Prestashop and translations are not working.

I have tried to add to .htaccess:

```
php_value max_input_vars 6000
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 6000
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 6000
```

And after that I cannot access my page, I get I get page not found error?

Can you help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: A 404 error has nothing to do with the settings you show above. A 500 error would

Comment: I get Page Not Found when I put that in htaccess, maybe it is just sending me to that page, not sure. But why?

Comment: You'll need to add more detail. What happens when you call which URL and why is max_input_vars a problem in the first place, how do you see its effect?

Comment: When I add that to my htaccess my page stops working and just get  Page not found error, nothing else. And when I remove htaccess page works after that normally. It happens on any url, I cannot access any link on my page

Comment: It seems you can't use `max_input_vars` with `5.2.17`. It is only available since PHP 5.3.9. Check this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php)

Comment: there is no override for this?
Then I will have to wait for hosting to upgrade to php 5.3

Comment: It is also available in available since [PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze7](http://ftp-master.metadata.debian.org/changelogs//main/p/php5/php5_5.3.3-7+squeeze17_changelog), but you have to have suhosin installed

Comment: `max_input_vars` truncates the request, it doesn't throw an error. Having your request truncated might lead to http error if script is expecting vars to be set.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should work, If you add

```
php_value max_input_vars 6000
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 6000
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 6000
```

to your `.htaccess`.

be sure, the webserver can read the .htaccess file you created and there are no other typos in that file.

If you get a blank page, check the errorlog of apache for errors:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log &
```

and if you have the rights: check the syslog too for errors when you restart apache:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog &
sudo apache2ctl restart
```