# Is there a limit like max_input_vars in versions before 5.3.9?

Tags: php, configuration

It seems like there is a problem with older PHP versions and more than 1000 input fields in one form ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309258/max-input-vars-limited-in-php-5-2-17)).

If I run a webserver with an older PHP version, **is there a limit** to the maximum number of form elements in (one nesting level) like it is controlled by the `php.ini` [directive max_input_vars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) since PHP 5.3.9?

Or is there **no limit** in older versions?

What happens if I set this variable anyway in older versions in php.ini or .htaccess?

I noticed, that on my server I run PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze17 which also already has the directive `max_input_vars`.

How exactly did older versions behave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in older versions:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65778

although you can alter the directive in php.ini and the change is shown correctly in `phpinfo()`, it has no effect.

**Behaviour:** all variables exceeding 1000 are ignored

tested in PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze17 without suhosin module

A possible workaround: [compact all form-data with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100554/compact-all-form-data-with-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

It seems there is confusion:

http://www.flowstopper.org/2012/12/my-php-wtf-of-day-maxinputvars.html

Although the docs say: "Available since PHP 5.3.9."

http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php

If I had to guess I would say there was always a limit, and it just got pulled out into the config/documentation in 5.3.9

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is not the number of yourform fields, I think the total data you are sending is to much.

There is an php.ini directive that limits how much data you totally can send on a post request (check: [post_max_size](http://www.php.net/manual/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)).

But you can not change `post_max_size` while runtime (because this value is checked before the first line of you php files during input phase of php).

Your have several ways to change this value:

1. In Webserver Config
2. in a htaccess file

with the following code:

```
php_value post_max_size 512M # set maximum post data to 512 MB
```

1. in your global php.ini
2. in your [users.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/configuration.file.per-user.php) (if it's configured)

with the following code:

```
post_max_size = 512M
```

Comment: I am aware of the post_max_size directive and your hints are all correct, but it is not connected to my question. I have a form with over 1000 radiobuttons, that could be hardly as much as a few MB. I really want to know about the variable **max_input_vars**

Comment: Sorry, but your question gives no information what kind of form elements you are talking about. I yust answered: 'there is **no limit** for the number of fields in PHP 5.3.3 but it has another limitation that may give a limit for input_vars'