# How does the behaviour of max_input_vars differ in different PHP versions?

Tags: php, configuration

Since PHP 5.3.9 there is the runtime configuration variable [max_input_vars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) in php.ini that limits the amount how many input variables may be accepted by one form.

But what exactly happens if the limit is exceeded (in versions *since 5.3.9*)?

1. Are the supernumerary variables **ignored**?
2. Or are **all variables discarded** if the limit is exceeded?

How exactly is this handled? And if variables are discarded, which? And did the behaviour change in different versions?

(also related: [Is there a limit like max_input_vars in versions before 5.3.9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042734/is-there-a-limit-like-max-input-vars-in-versions-before-5-3-9) )

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a limit like max\_input\_vars in versions before 5.3.9?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042734/is-there-a-limit-like-max-input-vars-in-versions-before-5-3-9)

Comment: The answers to your questions are covered in the link you posted in your question.

Comment: not at all, here I ask about the difference in newer versions than 5.3.9, in the other questions the behaviour before the introduction of the new variable

Answer (score 2):

Any variable over the limit is discarded, so your total variables are truncated.

From the link: `an E_WARNING is issued, and further input variables are truncated from the request`

The order they are supplied are the order they get cut off.

Comment: The question is how it is handled in different PHP versions