# compact all form-data with javascript

Tags: php

I would like to compact all data from a huge HTML-form with over a 1000 variables to circumvent the max_input_vars limit in PHP versions before 5.3.9.

How can I read all data in the HTML-form with javascript, serialize it (or create json) to put it all in only one hidden field that contains the whole data then?

On the receiving side I would uncompress it with PHP (for example with [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php))

Comment: Serialize the form using jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a script that does the job on all post forms automatically:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
// this disables all form elements and creates only one new element that contains all data serialized
$('form[method="post"]').submit(function() {
    var num_form_elements=$(this).find('input, select, textarea').not('[type="submit"]').length;
    var num_elements_already_disabled=$(this).find('input:disabled, select:disabled, textarea:disabled').length;
    enabled=(num_form_elements-num_elements_already_disabled);
    if($('textarea[name="serialized_data"]', this).length > 0) {
        alert("Backbutton is not supported yet!");
        return false;
    }
    if($('textarea[name="serialized_data"]', this).length > 0 || enabled<=0) {
        alert("Reload of the form is not supported yet!");
        return false;
    }
    var data=$(this).serialize();
    $(this).find('input, select, textarea').not('[type="submit"]').attr("disabled", true);
    $(this).append('    <input type="hidden" name="num_form_elements" value="'+num_form_elements+'">'); 
    $(this).append('    <input type="hidden" name="num_elements_already_disabled" value="'+num_elements_already_disabled+'">'); 
    $(this).append('    <textarea style="display:true" name="serialized_data">'+(data)+'</textarea>');
    // maybe in the textarea I have to .replace(/</g,'&lt;') ?

});
</script>
```

On the receiving side you cannot use the PHP `parse_str()` function because the max_input_vars directive affects this function too, so you need something else: I took `my_parse_str()` from https://gist.github.com/rubo77/6821632

```
<?php
    $params=my_parse_str($_REQUEST['serialized_data']);

    echo count($params,1)." serialized variables:<br>";
    var_export($params);
?>
```

Example script on https://gist.github.com/rubo77/6815945

Answer (score 1):

Just sent a ajax post?

### form.html with javascript

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" id="form">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="text" name="username">

  <button type="submit" id="sendForm">Send</button>
</form>

<!-- YOUR JAVASCRIPT -->
<script type="text/javacript">
  $('#sendForm').click(function() {

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: $('#form').attr('action'),
      data: $('#form').serialize(),
      success: function(data) {

        // WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE

      }
    });

    return false;
  });
</script>
```

### process.php

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    // other form fields here
}
```

Comment: This will work, although the user will stay on the sending page with an ajax solution. If you want to build a fix into an existing framework with a lot of pages, where this has to be applied, [my solution below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19107646/1069083) will change the form and send only the serilized data to the original target page. Then you can just change the Header-php-script in your framework to receive and unserialize the data.

Answer (score 0):

[Serialize it using JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).  You can then [parse the URL string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) using PHP.

Comment: parse_url will not help, I guess you meant parse_str. But that will not help either, (see my answer above)

Answer (score 0):

perhaps serialize and JSON.stringify may work together, though I have not tried it.