# How do I find out if an input with a certain name exists in a certain form?

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have an onclick event on all forms on the page:

```
$('form[method="post"]').click(function() {
    if($('textarea[name="serialized_data"]').length > 0) {
            alert("serialize_data already exists in this form!");
            return false;
        }
        var data=$(this).serialize();
        $(this).append('<textarea name="serialized_data">'+(data)+'</textarea>'); 
});
```

If you press a submitbutton and then on the target page press back in the browser, then this alert comes up.

But this solution stops on all forms.

How can I apply the alert only on the form that submitbutton was already pressed?

> If you wonder why I input all data in that textarea, that is another question: [compact all form-data with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100554/compact-all-form-data-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're selecting all `textarea`s anywhere, instead of those within the clicked form. Try this:

```
$('textarea[name="serialized_data"]', this)
```

That restricts the selector to the context of `this`, which is the form.

Comment: thanks, that was what I was searching for. It works!