# Why is max_input_vars directive available in PHP 5.3.3 in my server's PHP instance?

Tags: php, centos5

As per PHP's official Documentation [max_input_vars directive is available from PHP 5.3.9](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php).

My server's PHP version is as follows :

```
$ php -version
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Sep 30 2014 06:37:02) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

But with PHP 5.3.3, I am still able to set `max_input_vars` to any value other than the default value.

My server OS is CentOS release 5.11 (Final).

So can anyone explain to me how is this directive available in PHP 5.3.3 in my case ?

Comment: Here's a previous answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042734/is-there-a-limit-like-max-input-vars-in-versions-before-5-3-9

Answer (score 0):

Some distributions apparently backport changes from newer PHP versions.

http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#113334